# The group of points of an elliptic curve $E$ over a finite field $E(\mathbb{F}_q)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

For the group of an elliptic curve $E$ over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. If $E(\mathbb{F}_q)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, then $q=n^2+1$ or $q=n^2\pm n +1$ or $q=(n\pm 1)^2$.

I would like to prove the above statement. How could I proceed from $n|p-1$ to deduce the above result?

Comment: Why should we have  $2\sqrt{q}\le 2n$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'm thinking about using Hasse equality $||E(\mathbb{F}_q)|-q+1 |\leq2\sqrt q$

Comment: Probably this doesn't work then. I just don't know how to proceed. Could you give me some hint about this problem?

Comment: Here is a counterexample. Take $E\colon y^2=x^3+x$ with $q=5$. Then $n=2$ because of $E(\Bbb F_5)\cong \Bbb Z/2 \times \Bbb Z/2$, but $2\sqrt{q}>2n=4$.

Comment: Let me note that Dietrich's counterexample is not a counterexample to the original statement, just to the inequality $2\sqrt{q}\leq 2n$ you are trying to use in the proof.

Comment: Just in case: the Hasse inequality is $|\#E({\mathbb F}_q)−(q+1)|≤2\sqrt q$... I see in one of your comments to Dietrich that you have the opposite sign in front of the  $1$ (This is a repost of my original comment to correct MY typo.)

Comment: @peterag I indeed made a mistake. And now I have corrected the question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Could you give me some hint about this problem?". I have a hint, but it is not complete:
Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb F_q$. Then the Weil Pairing
$E(\Bbb F_q) \times E(\Bbb F_q)  \rightarrow \Bbb F_q^{\ast}$ shows that there exist positive integers $n_1$,$n_2$ such that
$$
E(\Bbb F_q) \cong \Bbb Z/n_1 \times \Bbb Z/n_2
$$
with $n_1 \mid {\rm gcd}(n_2,q-1)$. Since we have $n_1=n_2=n$, we have
$n\mid q-1$.